# Docusign API - on Cancel get url to return to

Tags: docusignapi

Using the API, I generate the document and place my tags. User goes to sign and decides to finish later. It passes an event="cancelled" to my callback. I make note in my system that they cancelled it. But how can I get them back to the form later? There is no "authentication" with this. I do all the authentication on my end. So I need a URL to send them back to. Using the URL the api gives me to load in iframe expires. So how do I sent them Back to document?

I use PHP by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 possible causes (there may be others):

1. A 'Signing ceremony UX URL' has a short time to live (300 seconds or less I believe) so ensure you are making the call to retrieve a URL right when the user intends to perform the signing session.
2. A 'Signing ceremony UX URL' can only be rendered once. Verify that you are in fact retrieving a new URL each time and not reusing the original URL.

See [this](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/signing-from-your-app) recipe from the DocuSign Developer Center. Repeat step 3 to retrieve a new URL to present to your user.